# Pig latin Limit operator applied to each group attribute

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to return only the five largest places based on population in each state.  I am also trying to sort the result by state name, with places in each state listed in declining order of population.  What I have currently gives me only the first five places with states and *not* the five largest places *for each state*.

```
-- Groups places by state name.
group_by_state_name_populated_place_name =
    GROUP project_using_state_name
    BY (state::name, place::name);

-- Counts population for each place in every state.
count_population_for_each_place_in_every_state =
    FOREACH group_by_state_name_populated_place_name
    GENERATE group.state::name AS state_name,
             group.place::name AS name,
             COUNT(project_using_state_name.population) AS population;

-- Orders population in each group found above to enable the use of limit.
order_groups_of_states_and_population =
    ORDER count_population_for_each_place_in_every_state 
    BY state_name ASC, population DESC, name ASC;

-- Limit the top 5 population for each state BUT currently returning just the first 5 tuples of the previous one and not 5 of each state.
limit_population =
    LIMIT order_groups_of_states_and_population 5;
```

Comment: can you add a sample input and expected output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code snippet may help

```
inp_data = load 'input_data.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (state:chararray,place:chararray,population:long);

req_stats = FOREACH(GROUP inp_data BY state) {
    ordered = ORDER inp_data BY population DESC;
    required = LIMIT ordered 5;
    GENERATE FLATTEN(required);
};

req_stats_ordered = ORDER req_stats BY state, population DESC;

DUMP req_stats_ordered;
```